# Cloning a VS Project from GitHub.com and it loads in VS as a file structure but not a VS Project

Tags: visual-studio, team-explorer

Using VS Team Explorer, I cloned this project https://github.com/nicomp42/CybersecurityGroupProject.

It loads into the Solution Explorer like this:
[image]

I have to double-click on the .sln file to make VS think it's a VS Solution. After that I able to work with the Solution and the Project in the Solution.

The original GitHub repo was created from a VS Solution and published it to GitHub using Team Explorer. Did I do something wrong or is it supposed to work this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a 'Folder View'. You can switch back to solution by 4-rd button on toolbar. If it is initially opened as Folder View, then you opened your project as folder (it happens after clone repo automatically) and just need to open *.sln file instead.

[image]

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks! I can see how that would be a security issue.